# Como criar uma CONSTRAINT CHECK no SQLServer para validar versões com RegEx

Tags: sql-server, regex

Olá estou criando uma tabela no SQLServer onde quero fazer a validação de um campo para só aceitar a máscara correta de versões, assim:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Versao (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    codigo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Versao] PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Versao_codigo] CHECK (codigo LIKE '%[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+%')
);
```

Meu problema é quando eu tento fazer a inserção de um registro mas não está funcionando, assim:

```sql
INSERT INTO Versao (codigo) VALUES ('0.123.0198651687.1');
```

Teoricamente, com base nesse teste que fiz no site [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3o41r) o regex validaria se o código usado contém somente números e que tenha 4 blocos com 3 pontos entre eles, Sendo assim porque meu SQL Server não quer aceitar o insert?

Answer (score 0):

Achei a solução logo após postar (rsrs), aqui está:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Versao (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    codigo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Versao] PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_Versao_codigo] CHECK (codigo LIKE '[0-9]%.[0-9]%.[0-9]%.[0-9]%')
);

CREATE INDEX [UX_Versao_codigo] ON Versao(codigo);

INSERT INTO Versao(codigo) VALUES ('0.0.0.1'), ('1230.0.123120.1');

SELECT * FROM Versao
```

meu problema é que eu estava entendendo o CHECK como só aceitar se estiver dentro